# Storing arrays of text into Parse database

Tags: javascript, html, database, parse-platform

I am creating a mail system where user A sends a piece of text to user B, user B stores the text in an array in a column called Inbox (which has the attribute array).

I create 5 users, the first 2 users responds with "POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/fjT08jUUk8 400 (Bad Request)"

HOWEVER, the last 3 users works perfectly fine. I'm really frustrated because I just can't figure out what the problem is. All the users are created with the same conditions.

I'll link the code used here:

```
<textarea name="msg" id="msg" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
<button ng-click="sendMessage(fetched_user.id)">Send</button>
```

(fetched_user.id is the corresponding id for the user you're targeting, double checked it)

```
$scope.sendMessage = function(UID) {     
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    query.equalTo('objectId', UID);
    query.first({
        success: function(object) {
            var text = $('#msg').val();
            object.add("Inbox", text );
            object.save();
            $scope.$apply();    
        },
        error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }

    });
}
```

As always I'm really greatful for any kind of answer!! Thanks in advance :)

SOLVED!!!!

After a lot of research I found that object.save() was the problem and that it was giving me this error: Error: 206 Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError

I believe that this is some kind of security measure, that not everyone can alter users as they like. This has to be done from cloud code, which per say is a whole other department. So for you guys who want to get this done, get your reading into Parse Cloud Code!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the calling user of any cloud function by using `request.user`, which is a pointer to a user and should be used rather than passing an objectId.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I would make it look like this: query.equalTo('objectId', request.user); I've been searching around for request.user, but nothing valueable has come up

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason to query for users if you are only needing to get the requesting user. If you are modifying attributes of the requesting user, just make sure to call save when done. It may also be beneficial for you to add `console.log(request.user);` so you can see what information is contained.

Comment: I'm sorry but I only get a "request is not defined". Are you sure there is not more to it than "console.log(request.user);"

Comment: Oops this isn't part of cloud code, sorry for the confusion. In cloud code, the function has the request object automatically created. In your case, you can use `var user = Parse.User.current();` to get the current user, however that does not seem to be your problem. My guess is the bad request error is due to passing an incorrectly structured UID. Try printing out the UID before each query to make sure it is correct.

Comment: I have done that and it seems to be correct! However, I found that the problem is within "object.save()" where I get this error: "Error: 206 Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError". After some research it turns out that I can't manage other users without using cloud code.. I have no idea what so ever how to use cloud code so that's fun

Comment: Glad to hear you found the problem! Cloud code is amazingly powerful and you should honestly try to perform as much logic as possible from there. Cloud code gives you immense flexibility toward on-the-fly fixes/updates because of the deployment structure. Furthermore, you can also call cloud code from any of the Parse SDKs so you can reuse the logic cross-platform in mobile apps or elsewhere. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I will continue my research, this problem is getting on my nerves haha.. Thanks for the responses you gave! Have a good one